# I am trying to launch chrome browser using selenium and maven dependencies getting issue like java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I am using below versions of selenium java and server and cucumber dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.47.1</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.47.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
info.cukes cucumber-java 1.1.8
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8</version>
    </dependency>
com.theoryinpractise cucumber-testng-factory 1.0.1
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

But, If i am using same versions of jar files in ant and trying to launch chrome browser it is working. If i am using same version of dependencies in maven getting issue for launching chrome browser.

Getting below error for maven:

> /* java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
>       at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:52)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:56)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:46)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:72)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:84)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:59)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalConnectionFactory.(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:487)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:147)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:136)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:112)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:74)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.(HttpClientFactory.java:57)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.(HttpClientFactory.java:60)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.getDefaultHttpClientFactory(ApacheHttpClient.java:252)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.(ApacheHttpClient.java:229)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.getDefaultClientFactory(HttpCommandExecutor.java:96)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.(HttpCommandExecutor.java:70)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.(HttpCommandExecutor.java:58)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.(DriverCommandExecutor.java:49)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:170)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:138))*/

Comment: Why `<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId><version>2.47.1</version>`? Why not `<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try following set of selenium dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
```

Comment: Why `<version>3.14.0</version>` ? Why not `<version>3.141.59</version>`

Comment: I use 3.14.0 in my project. And found that after upgrade to this version the issue has been fixed. But I think it will work on the latest release (3.141.59) too. It is good idea to check.

Comment: First of all, I am very thankful to @DebanjanB and i.bondarenko                                        It is working for me                                                                                                    I have used below dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I have used below dependencies

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>25.0-jre</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-exec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-exec</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.28.0</version>
    </dependency>
```